# include directory in vcs option in Makefile

Tags: unix, makefile, system-verilog

I am working on one makefile let me give you quick view

vcs is tool, `+incdir+<dir_path>` is syntax

when i do `+incdir+${$@_${seed}}` its not working

`${seed}` is variable which I define in starting of my makefile

Regards,
Vinay

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? What does `${$@_${seed}}` expand to, and what did you expect? Does the entire command work on the command line? This is in a command, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the resoultion it should `+incdir+{$@_${seed}} ...`

Comment: Your question & answer seem very specific to your situation, which you haven't explained clearly. If the makefile target is `foo`, a variable `seed` is set to 100 and a variable `foo_100` is set to the include directory path, `+incdir+${$@_${seed}}` works perfectly.

On the other hand `+incdir+{$@_${seed}}` expands to `+incdir+{foo_100}` which would work if the include directory is named `{foo_100}` (which looks strange as using braces in filenames is rare).